# Horizontal standard error bars on bar graphs with negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar graph that looks this:
[image: Horizontal Bar Graph]

and I am trying to get standard error bars on it - so two standard error bars for each column (one for the positive Y, and one for the negative N). I am aware of geom_errorh, but I cannot get it to work for this type of bar graph. 
Here is a reproducible example with the code that I used to get a bar chart like the one above:

## Dataframe

```
Behavior<-as.character(c("Hammock","Hammock","Climbing Trees","Climbing Trees","Structures","Structures","Grade","Grade"))
Presence<-c("Y","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y","N")
Mean<-as.numeric(c("18.5", "-6.4","3.5","-6.8","13.2","-10.1","4.7","-2.3"))
SD<-as.numeric(c("17.6","-11.9","1.2","-4.4","3.6","-6.25","1.23","-0.4"))
DF<-data.frame(Behavior,Presence,Mean,SD)
```

## Coord Flip Geom Bar

```
brks <- seq(-20, 20, 2)
lbls = paste0(as.character(c(seq(-20, 0, 2), seq(2, 20, 2))), "")



ggplot(DF, aes(x = Behavior, y = Mean, fill = Presence )) + 
      geom_bar(data = subset(DF, Presence == "N"), stat = "identity") +
      geom_bar(data = subset(DF, Presence == "Y"), stat = "identity") +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks,labels = lbls) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0b6bb6", "#6eaf46"),name="", breaks=c("N", "Y"),labels=c("N", "Y"))+
      coord_flip()+  
      theme_bw()+
      xlab("Pen Characteristic - Behavior")+
      ylab("Average Behavior per Session")+
```

Is it possible to get the SE bars on this type of graph?

Thanks!

Comment: SD stands for standard deviation, right? SD can not be a negative number.

Comment: @JakubBuček oh I apologize I guess I spaced out while making that dummy dataframe - the SD should be SE for standard error.

Comment: @JakubBuček i also just realized what you actually meant by your comment and you are right SD can never be a negative number haha thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jakub pointed out in his comment, SD values are positive values.

What you normally do is something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

Behavior <- as.character(c(
  "Hammock","Hammock",
  "Climbing Trees","Climbing Trees",
  "Structures","Structures",
  "Grade","Grade"))
Presence <- c("Y","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y","N")
Mean <- as.numeric(
  c("18.5", "-6.4",
    "3.5","-6.8",
    "13.2","-10.1",
    "4.7","-2.3"))
SD <- as.numeric(c(
  "17.6","-11.9",
  "1.2","-4.4",
  "3.6","-6.25",
  "1.23","-0.4"))
my_sd <- runif(length(Behavior))
DF <- data.frame(Behavior,Presence,Mean,SD, my_sd)

brks <- seq(-20, 20, 2)

ggplot(DF, 
       aes(x=Behavior, y=Mean, fill=Presence )) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0b6bb6", "#6eaf46"),
                    name="", 
                    breaks=c("N", "Y"),
                    labels=c("N", "Y")) +
  coord_flip()+  
  theme_bw()+
  xlab("Pen Characteristic - Behavior") +
  ylab("Average Behavior per Session") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean - my_sd, ymax=Mean + my_sd))
```

Comment: this is perfect thank you so much!! (I also meant SE, not SD - I must have spaced out while making the dummy df)

Comment: I also understand the no negative SD comment now thank you!